# Why does std::ostream not compile when used in ternary operator?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, ostream

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ostream o(nullptr);
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : std::ostream(nullptr); // A
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : o; //B
    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering why `A` compiles fine while `B` fails with error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7:33: error: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected within this context
  true ? o : std::ostream(nullptr);
                                 ^
```

So I found this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/conditional-operator-q?view=vs-2017 which says that when ternary operator has arguments (by "arguments" I mean the ones to the left and right of `:`) then it can cause copying of arguments, casting etc... Which would make sense since `std::ostream` has copy constructors defined as `protected`. So in `A` the ternary operator gets both arguments of the same type, no copying is done so there's no problem. Whereas in `B` the ternary operator gets arguments of different types which apparently causes the need for copying which is not allowed for `std::ostream`. Everything seems OK so far.

But then I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ostream o(nullptr);
    std::ostream & oRef = o;
    std::ostream && oRRef = std::ostream(nullptr);
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : std::ostream(nullptr); // A
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : o; //B
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : oRef; // C
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : oRRef; // D
    true ? std::ostream(nullptr) : std::move(oRRef); // E
    return 0;
}
```

`C`, `D` and `E` also fail with similar errors.

So I have a few questions. What is the type of the expression: `std::ostream(nullptr)`? Is it true that the ternary operator will make copies of its arguments when they have different types but will never make copies when they're of the same type? Anything else I missed or need to know?

Comment: What exactly do you think this `std::ostream o(nullptr);` is doing?

Comment: Creating an instance of `std::ostream`. Other than that I don't know.

Comment: So you just wrote it at random?

Comment: That was my attempt to create an instance of `std::ostream` that passed compilation. I needed only that to understand how it works, my final code wouldn't use it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard contains some complicated rules regarding how the conditional expression is evaluated ([expr.cond]). But instead of quoting those rules here, I'm going to explain how you should think about them.

The result of the conditional expression can be an lvalue, xvalue, or prvalue. But which one of these it is has to be known at compile time. (The value category of an expression can never depend on what happens at runtime). It's easy to see that if both the second and third expressions are lvalues of the same type, then the result can also be made an lvalue, and no copying has to occur. If both the second and third expressions are prvalues of the same type, then, as of C++17, no copying has to occur either---a prvalue of type `T` represents the deferred initialization of an object of type `T`, and the compiler simply chooses, based on the condition, which of those two prvalues gets passed on to eventually be used to initialize an object.

But when one expression is an lvalue and the other is a prvalue of the same type, then the result must be a prvalue. If the standard said the result would be an lvalue, that would be illogical, as the condition may cause the prvalue operand to be selected, and you can't convert a prvalue into an lvalue. But you can do it the other way around. So the standard says that when one operand is an lvalue and the other is a prvalue of the same type, then the lvalue must undergo the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. And if you attempt an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an `std::ostream` object, the program will be ill-formed since the copy constructor is deleted.

Thus:

- In A, both operands are prvalues so there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion; this is ok in C++17 (but not in C++14).
- In B, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is needed for `o`, so this won't compile.
- In C, `oRef` is an lvalue so the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is still required, so this also won't compile.
- In D, `oRRef` is still an lvalue (as the name of an rvalue reference is an lvalue).
- In E, one argument is a prvalue and one is an xvalue. The xvalue still needs to be converted into a prvalue to make the result a prvalue.

The case of E deserves some further remarks. In C++11 it was clear that if one argument is an xvalue and the other is a prvalue of the same type, the xvalue must undergo the (misleadingly named) lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to yield a prvalue. In the case of `std::ostream`, this uses the protected move constructor (so the program violates member access control). In C++17, one could contemplate changing the rule so that instead of the xvalue being converted to a prvalue, the prvalue gets materialized to yield an xvalue instead, obviating the need for a move. But this change has no obvious benefit and it's questionable whether it's the most reasonable behaviour, so that's probably why it wasn't made (if it were even considered).